# iOS StackView or CollectionView

Tags: ios, xamarin, view, xamarin.ios, grid

I have to make a grid with a specific architecture.

I don't know if I have to use a stackView with views? Or a collectionView with cell?

Let's see my image :

[image]

Green cells will be repeated infinite times.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and best way do make this is collection view, Also in collection views cells(items) are reused, so you don't need to release them after they have disappeared.

Comment: Even if each cell has différent content ?

Comment: Yes, you can use dynamic collectionViews and implement delegate, datasource, to change their content at runtime

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the number of grid cells. If the number of cells is 2~4, it's OK to use stackView.

But

> Green cells will be repeated infinite times.

So, you should use collection view. Collection view is suitable for displaying repeating layouts like your image or calendar app on iOS.
And offscreen collection view cell(table view cell also) is reusable, so you only create cells enough to fill the screen and a little more.
[See Table View Cell Reuse Explanation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell)